# Window scroll function lag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that positions a div depending on the webpages position.

```
function calcNav(){
    var b = $('#breadcrumb').offset().top;
    var w = $(window).scrollTop();
    var x = b - w;
    //console.log('breadcrumb from top = ' + b + ' window scrolled = ' + w + ' position of nav = ' + x);
    $('.sub-nav').css('top', x);
}
calcNav();
$(window).scroll(calcNav);
```

The function works great, my only issue is that as its constantly rendering my page speed appears a bit laggy - is there any way I can run the function at the end of the scroll instead of during?

Comment: If you are not expecting the top offset of `#breadcrumb` to change you can define it outside the calcNav() function so it gets calculated only once

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to you use it with combination with `setTimeout` and add small amount of milliseconds:

```
var scrollTimeout;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout( scrollTimeout );
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout( calcNav, 50 );
});
```

`clearTimeout` in this case is used to not trigger previous call if next scroll event was triggered less than 50ms, in case you think your users will scroll slower you can increase this value for example to 100ms etc.